# Отображение объекта в tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Есть обьект salary{id, year, month, empl{id, name, adress}}

так мы отображаем и всё работает, но как сделать это с объектом empl?

```
salaryYear.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Salary, String>("years"));
```

Пробую так,

```
salaryFirstName.setCellValueFactory(cellData  -> cellData.getValue().getEmployeesByEmpl().getFirstName());
```

но пишет

```
"bad return type in lambda expression
java.lang.String cannot be converted to javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue<java.lang.String>"
```

Вот как всё происходит. Есть таблица, есть лист с данными.

1)Вот эти поля отображаются

```
salaryYear.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Salary, String>("years"));
 salaryMonth.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Salary, String>("month"));
```

а это нет,

```
salaryFirstName.setCellValueFactory(cellData  -> cellData.getValue().getEmployeesByEmpl().getFirstName());
```

2) Данные пытаюсь отобразить вот так:

```
employees.setAll(Factory.getEmplDAO().getAllEmpl());
tableEmpl.setItems(employees);
```

Было бы хорошо, если бы не нужно было менять entity.
Как можно это исправить

Comment: Приведи полный код таблицы, как ты делаешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепише так

```
salaryFirstName.setCellValueFactory(cellData  -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getEmployeesByEmpl().getFirstName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод `getFirstName()` должен возвращать не просто строку, а [StringProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html).

Comment: Это не обязательное условие. Ты можешь сам задать SimpleObjectProperty<T>()